# How convert this Pytorch loss function to Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

This Code for a paper I read had a loss function written using Pytorch, I tried to convert it as best as I could but am getting all Zero's as model predictions, so would like to ask the following:

1. Are the methods I used the correct equivalent in Tensorflow?
2. Why is the model predicting only Zero's?

Here is the function:

```
#Pytorch

class AdjMSELoss1(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(AdjMSELoss1, self).__init__()
            
def forward(self, outputs, labels):
    outputs = torch.squeeze(outputs)
    alpha = 2
    loss = (outputs - labels)**2
    adj = torch.mul(outputs, labels)
    adj[adj>0] = 1 / alpha
    adj[adj<0] = alpha
    loss = loss * adj
    return torch.mean(loss)

#Tensorflow

def custom_loss_function(outputs,labels):
    outputs = tf.squeeze(outputs)
    alpha = 2.0
    loss = (outputs - labels) ** 2.0
    adj = tf.math.multiply(outputs,labels)

    adj = tf.where(tf.greater(adj, 0.0), tf.constant(1/alpha), adj)
    adj = tf.where(tf.less(adj, 0.0), tf.constant(alpha), adj)

    loss = loss * adj

    return  tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

The function compiles correctly and is being used in the loss and metric parameters, it is outputing results in metrics logs that appear to be correct (Similar to val_loss) ***but the output of the model after running is just predicting all 0's***

```
 model.compile(
        loss= custom_loss_function, 
        optimizer=optimization,
        metrics = [custom_loss_function]
    )
```

**MODEL**

```
#Simplified for readability
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(SEQ_LEN,feature_number),return_sequences=True,))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(96, return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1))

return model
```

Inputs/Features are pct_change Price for the previous SEQ_LEN days. (Given SEQ_LEN days tries to predict next day: Target)

Outputs/Targets are the next day's price pct_change * 100 (Ex: 5 for 5%). (1 value per row)

***Note: The model predicts normally when RMSE() is set as the loss function, as mentioned when using the custom_loss_function above it's just predicting Zero's***

Comment: I can't understand update part...

Comment: I'm running my LSTM model using the custom_loss_function mentioned above as the loss parameter, and although the custom loss function as a metric is giving out results similar to the normal loss function, the models prediction output however is just all Zero's. @l'mahdi

Comment: OK, send your model and data, then maybe we can check your model and data and improve accuracy and decrease loss/

Comment: Added, though i believe the issue is with this custom loss function as it normally predicts fine with any other loss function.  @l'mahdi

Comment: Do your model work well on your data with other loss function?

Comment: As mentioned above yes, i'm not seeking to optimise this function, now i just want this loss function to work at all :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this `custom_loss`:

```
def custom_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    alpha = 2.0
    loss = (y_pred - y_true) ** 2.0
    adj = tf.math.multiply(y_pred,y_true)
    adj = tf.where(tf.greater(adj, 0.0), tf.constant(1/alpha), adj)
    adj = tf.where(tf.less(adj, 0.0), tf.constant(alpha), adj)
    loss = loss * adj
    return  tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

I check with the below code and work correctly *(Code for creating a model for learning and predicting the sum of two variables with the **`custom_loss`**)*:

```
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

x = np.random.rand(1000,2)
y = x.sum(axis=1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

def custom_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    alpha = 2.0
    loss = (y_pred - y_true) ** 2.0
    adj = tf.math.multiply(y_pred,y_true)
    adj = tf.where(tf.greater(adj, 0.0), tf.constant(1/alpha), adj)
    adj = tf.where(tf.less(adj, 0.0), tf.constant(alpha), adj)
    loss = loss * adj
    return  tf.reduce_mean(loss)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_dim=2)) 
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1,)) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss) 
model.fit(x, y, epochs=200, batch_size=16)

for _ in range(10):
    rnd_num = np.random.randint(50, size=2)[None, :]
    pred_add = model.predict(rnd_num)
    print(f'predict sum of {rnd_num[0]} -> {pred_add}')
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/200
63/63 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2903
Epoch 2/200
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0084
Epoch 3/200
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0016
...
Epoch 198/200
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 3.3231e-07
Epoch 199/200
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 5.1004e-07
Epoch 200/200
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 9.8688e-08

predict sum of [43 44] -> [[82.81973]]
predict sum of [39 13] -> [[48.97299]]
predict sum of [36 46] -> [[78.05187]]
predict sum of [46  7] -> [[49.445843]]
predict sum of [35 11] -> [[43.311478]]
predict sum of [33  1] -> [[31.695848]]
predict sum of [6 8] -> [[13.433815]]
predict sum of [14 38] -> [[49.54941]]
predict sum of [ 1 40] -> [[39.709686]]
predict sum of [10  2] -> [[11.325197]]
```

Comment: I've tried it but still getting all Zeros as ouptuts.  Could you clarify why you think squeezing the values would be wrong ?  @l'mahdi

Comment: @YassinSameh, Because the shape of `y_true` and `y_pred` same as each other and you don't need squeezing.

Comment: @YassinSameh, I add another code block. Check this.